# How to monitor window selection change event in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any method to monitor the change event of window.selection?

Something like a callback, to be invoked when user select different content.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, and you want to handle select on a specific item with an ID of `myInput`, you can do this:

```
$("#myInput").select(function() { alert("Something was selected!"); });
```

Otherwise, I think you'd need to add it in HTML, like this:

```
<input type="text" onSelect="alert('foo');" value="default text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [onSelect](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp) handler.