# How to bind a handler to a selection change on window?

Tags: javascript, selection, dom-events

Basically I need to know when the `window.getSelection()` has changed and bind a handler to this event. Ideas?

OBS: Please note that I'm not looking to bind a selection change on a INPUT or TEXTAREA. I'm talking about any selection in the window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor window selection change event in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139623/how-to-monitor-window-selection-change-event-in-javascript)

Comment: not a duplicate because I need to monitor the window selection event, not for a input

Comment: Actually I think it is a duplicate, as the other question does seem to be asking the same thing rather imprecisely, but the answers there are not useful. A better duplicate is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442158/selection-change-event-in-contenteditable

Answer (score 19):

**2019 update**

All major browsers now support the [`selectionchange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event), which does the job. Firefox was the last browser to get it, and it has had it without a configuration flag since version 52 (released in March 2017).

**Original answer**

There is no cross-browser way of detecting changes to the selection. IE (since version 5.5, I think) and WebKit/Blink browsers (Chrome, Safari and Opera version from the last couple of years, for example) support a `selectionchange` event on the `document` which does exactly what you want.

Firefox and pre-Blink Opera have no such event and all you can do is detect selection changes made via keyboard and mouse events, which is unsatisfactory (there is no way of detecting "Select All" from context or edit menus, for example), or simply poll the `Selection` object returned by `window.getSelection()` (checking the selection's `anchorNode`, `anchorOffset`, `focusNode` and `focusOffset` properties against their previous values should be sufficient).

Comment: Update: Opera now supports selectionchange (since the switch to Blink). For work, I recently wrote a lightweight selectionchange polyfill for Firefox. https://github.com/2is10/selectionchange-polyfill The Firefox feature request, for tracking purposes: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571294

Comment: @jaredjacobs: Thanks. I've incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: It got into FF43, but you still need to change a flag. Should be available soon then. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange#Browser_compatibility

Comment: In FF52, it's no longer behind a flag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event FF52 was released 2 years ago, we should be good.

Comment: @JoshPowlison: That's good news. I've incorporated that into my answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9):

There is no cross-browser event for that.

However, there does exist an event called `selectionchange`, which trigger on every change in a selection in the document, but it is only supported in IE and recent WebKit (Chrome/Safari), so no Firefox/Opera.

You can use the `selectionchange` event like this:

```
$(document).on('selectionchange', function(e) {
    console.log('selectionchange', e.originalEvent); 
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/KEHAv/)

Comment: ^ This. However, it is extremely greedy and may fire many times a second, similar to `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that the `selectionchange` event is too greedy, and you want to watch the mouse events.
The handler is the easy part.  **Returning the selected nodes**  is the important part!
Adapting [Tim Down's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781963/js-get-array-of-all-selected-nodes-in-contenteditable-div) this is what I came up with:

```
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) { 
    
            //cool! jQuery object containing all nodes (elements) that were just selected
            var $selNodes = $().getSelectedNodes();
            if ($selNodes.length)
                     alert('user selected something');
            
            //so now I can do work on just the elements I am interested in that were selected
            if($selNodes.filter('.justTheClassIwant').length)
                alert('user selected the elements I want to watch');
        });
    
    jQuery.fn.extend({
    getSelectedNodes: function() {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                var node = range.startContainer;
                var endNode = range.endContainer;

                // Special case for a range that is contained within a single node
                if (node == endNode) {
                    return [node];
                }

                // Iterate nodes until we hit the end container
                var rangeNodes = [];
                while (node && node != endNode) {
                    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                        node = node.firstChild;
                    } 
                    else {
                        while (node && !node.nextSibling) {
                            node = node.parentNode;
                        }
                        node = node.nextSibling;
                    }
    
                    rangeNodes.push(node);
                }

                // Add partially selected nodes at the start of the range
                node = range.startContainer;
                while (node && node != range.commonAncestorContainer) {
                    rangeNodes.unshift(node);
                    node = node.parentNode;
                }

                return jQuery(rangeNodes);
            }
        }
        return jQuery([]);
    }
});
```