# Manipulating selection and retrieving parent properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

User comment looks something like this:

```
<div id="comment23" class="commentholder">
    <p>
        This is a sample comment. It may contain different kinds of html.
        like <strong>strong text</strong>
        or anything that markdown supports.
    </p>
</div>
```

When text in comment23 div is selected, I would like to display a button near it. If button is pressed I want to take the selected text, prepend ">" to each line (to make it blockquote in markdown) and paste it in an input box.

How can I achieve this in javascript, preferably jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to read up on [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) objects. If you want to support IE < 9, which has a completely different selection API from other browsers, you'll need to [read up about that too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll also need to simulate the `selectionchange` event, which exists in WebKit and IE but not Firefox and Opera.

I've answered all the constituent parts of this on SO before. Here's a couple of links:

- [How to bind a handler to a selection change on window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991511/how-to-bind-a-handler-to-a-selection-change-on-window/9035122#9035122)
- [how to get selection inside a div using jquery/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801347/how-to-get-selection-inside-a-div-using-jquery-javascript/5801903#5801903)